# Dependency and duplicates error, during installation of HHVM on Redhat

Tags: redhat, hhvm

I installed HHVM on Redhat-6.6 (Santiago) `using yum install hhvm`, But it returns Following errors

```
Error: Package: gcc-java-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
 Requires: gcc = 4.4.7-17.el6
             Removing: gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.7-11.el6
                        Updated By: gcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
                            gcc = 4.8.2-8.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.4-13.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.5-6.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.5-6.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.6-3.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.6-4.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.7-3.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.7-4.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.7-4.1.el6_5.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.7-4.1.el6_5
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6_5
                        Available: gcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.7-16.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
                            gcc = 4.4.7-17.el6
                            gcc = 4.4.4-15.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.6.3-2.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
                            gcc = 4.6.3-2.el6
                        Available: gcc-4.8.2-7.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
                            gcc = 4.8.2-7.el6  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
             ** Found 8 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows: 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-51.P1.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with
             12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-43.P1.el6_6.1.x86_64
             glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with
             glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
             glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc =
             ('0', '2.12', '1.192.el6') kernel-headers-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64 is
             a duplicate with kernel-headers-2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
             libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with
             libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 ncurses-base-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64 is a
             duplicate with ncurses-base-5.7-3.20090208.el6.x86_64
             nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.3.el6_8.x86_64 is a duplicate with
             nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-22.el6_6.x86_64 tzdata-2016f-1.el6.noarch is
             a duplicate with tzdata-2015a-1.el6.noarch
```

I tried The following

```
yum clean all
rpm --rebuilddb
yum update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system has multiple problems here that need to be fixed:

- First, you have rpmdb problems (duplicate packages) because a previous run of `yum` was interrupted. You can try to [clean this up](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/38644) with:

  ```
  yum-complete-transaction   # which may fail
  package-cleanup --cleandupes
  ```
- Second, your system has a third party repository named `hop5` which is providing packages that conflict with the packages provided by RHEL. This repository needs to be [disabled](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html) or removed. If you were actually using packages from this repository, you should instead get them from official RHEL sources, or for third party packages, a more reliable source.

  ```
  yum-config-manager --disable hop5
  ```
- Finally, your system appears to be [locked](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/238533) onto RHEL 6.6, and you need to update to the current release (today 6.8). You can fix this with:

  ```
  subscription-manager release --unset
  yum --releasever=6.8 update
  ```